# Return non-zero value:error 9, while building make user in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, root

I am trying to build docker container in ubuntu 14.04 but i am facing below error....

```
Step 1/6 : FROM extras
 ---> 2427883089fe
Step 2/6 : ARG UID
 ---> Running in be1df930d560
 ---> eeafcc0e6b56
Removing intermediate container be1df930d560
Step 3/6 : ARG UNAME
 ---> Running in cc76b60de074
 ---> ac3ce9ae6bce
Removing intermediate container cc76b60de074
Step 4/6 : RUN useradd -u ${UID} ${UNAME}     && mkdir /home/${UNAME}     && echo 'echo "___                                   "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " |   _      _ |_      _   _ |_ |_     "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " |  |  |_| _) |_ \)/ (_) |  |_ | ) \/ "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "                                   /  "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " __                                   "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "(_      _ |_  _  _   _                "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "__) \/ _) |_ (- ||| _)                "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "    /                                 "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "Hello, welcome to the sel4/CAmkES/L4v docker build environment"' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'export PATH=/scripts/repo:$PATH' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'cd /host' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && ln -s /isabelle /home/${UNAME}/.isabelle     && mkdir -p /isabelle     && chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /isabelle     && chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /home/${UNAME}     && chmod -R ug+rw /home/${UNAME}


 ---> Running in 2104337eb219
**useradd: user 'root' already exists**
Removing intermediate container 2104337eb219


The command '/bin/sh -c useradd -u ${UID} ${UNAME}     && mkdir /home/${UNAME}     && echo 'echo "___                                   "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " |   _      _ |_      _   _ |_ |_     "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " |  |  |_| _) |_ \)/ (_) |  |_ | ) \/ "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "                                   /  "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo " __                                   "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "(_      _ |_  _  _   _                "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "__) \/ _) |_ (- ||| _)                "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "    /                                 "' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'echo "Hello, welcome to the sel4/CAmkES/L4v docker build environment"' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'export PATH=/scripts/repo:$PATH' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && echo 'cd /host' >> /home/${UNAME}/.bashrc     && ln -s /isabelle /home/${UNAME}/.isabelle     && mkdir -p /isabelle     && chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /isabelle     && chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /home/${UNAME}     && chmod -R *****ug+rw /home/${UNAME}' returned a non-zero code: 9
make: *** [build_user] Error** 9***
```

I am following these steps

https://github.com/SEL4PROJ/seL4-CAmkES-L4v-dockerfiles

while doing make user i am getting these kind of error can anyone please suggest me how to solve these errors...

Comment: Could somebody with 1500+ reputation create a tag "seL4", so it could be added here?  Seems there is some work in a seL4 specific Q/A site for stack overflow: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120611/sel4

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a container of Ubuntu 14.04 just try

```
docker run ubuntu:14.04
```

What this command will do it will search for ubuntu 14.04 imaget locally. if not founf will download from docker hub

and your image will be downloaded and started. 
Link which you have added in issue is doing lot of fancy work.

If this works you can create your own dockerfile further.